# Hiding HTML element in GeckoWebBrowser (C#)

Tags: c#, html, geckofx

I'm trying to make a little program in C# using Gecko; I want to load some webpage in Gecko, search for specific element and hide it to be invisible for user. I wrote that code and it works in WebBrowser (based on IE) but similiar code doesn't work with Gecko. This is what I made in WebBrowser:

```
HtmlElement h1 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
if (h1 != null)
{
   h1.Style = "display:none";
}
```

I know how to search for element in Gecko but how to make this element invisible?

Thanks,
Jakub

Comment: are you familiar with `CSS` do a google search on for examples on how to use `display:none`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works in GeckoFX 45. You can use the SetAttribute method to set the style of a given element.

```
GeckoHtmlElement someElement = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
someElement.SetAttribute("style", @"display: none;");
```